# How can I turn a url with get method as a clean url with segment as the get method?

Tags: php, url-rewriting

I got a page called profile

my current way to view the profile of user 1

```
www.sample.com/profile/?id=1
```

how can I make this something like this

```
www.sample.com/profile/1/
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it

```
function rewrite_profile() {
  add_rewrite_rule('^profile/([0-9]+)/?', 'profile/?id=$matches[1]', 'bottom');
}
add_action('init', 'rewrite_profile');
```

I still don't know if this is the right way.